# Which is the best choice of getting bonds data from?

Tags: data-request, finance

I have to find some data of Germany, Greece 10 years bonds and risk premium from 2017 up to now. I found some sources,

1. https://countryeconomy.com/bonds/germany
2. https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/GDBR10:IND
3. https://www.investing.com/rates-bonds/germany-10-year-bond-yield-historical-data

but there exist some differences between them. For example, in the first site, the yield on 05/09/2019  was given -0.04%. In Bloomberg, it was given -0.05%.
Which one is trustworthy? Does anyone know the reason for which this difference arises? Is there any other source that I can check?